# Using Or in a mask for .loc[...] with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to work with Or conditions accross multiple columns in pandas?

I have been trying .loc[...] with a mask, but it returns everything or fails.

```
### Accounts older than renewal date
mask = (Accounts['Valid to'] < renewal_date) | (Accounts['Signed'].isnull())
print(Accounts.loc[mask])
```

Ideally, I am looking for accounts older than the renewal date or if the account has not signed up (blank cell).
Thanks

Comment: The code seems fine. Please provide an example (minimal !) that doesn't do what you expect

Comment: As @VladimirFokow wrote - your code is fine. It is probably that the empty cells are not Nulls and/or the 'Valid to' column is not formatted proparly

Comment: @gtomer  - dates above 2500 has been converted to NaT with pd.to_datetime(Accounts['Valid to'], errors = 'coerce') including blank cells (which I didn't want to happen on blank cells)